# Database default values lead to unexpected Minitest result

Tags: ruby-on-rails, minitest

A Rails 7.0 migration includes the attribute `t.bigint :status_id, default: 6`
Which is invoked in the model as

```
belongs_to :status, class_name: 'Categoryminor'
```

If a test is run

```
shop = Shop.new(name: 'apatride')
assert shop.valid?
```

the Unit test will complain `#<ActiveModel::Errors [#<ActiveModel::Error attribute=status, type=blank, options={:message=>:required}>]>` notwithstanding the schema clearly states `t.bigint "status_id", default: 6` and verifying with postgresql, that default value is well defined there.

Changing the class

```
belongs_to :status, class_name: 'Categoryminor', optional: true
```

allows the test to pass, but this is somewhat non-sensical.  If there is a default value, the attribute cannot be blank.

What is the reasoning going on here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`belongs_to` relations have presence validation since rails 5. Putting a random status_id is not enough. There must be a record in `CategoryMinor` table with the id of 6, and in the case of tests, the fixture has to be properly invoked.

Two material ways to resolve this:

- add an id value to the fixture `status:  id: 6`
- write the test to call the fixture object without the id `
  The latter is not pithier, but less prone to further complications.